# W3C Validator error: "Tab, new line or carriage return found."

Tags: html, magento-1.9, w3c-validation

What are the required changes to remove this error?

> Bad value `https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1895932367347929&ev=PageView↩&noscript=1` for attribute `src` on element `img`: Tab, new line or carriage return found.

I’m using Magento.

Comment: It's plain impossible that a Facebook link contains a carriage return so you must have made a transcription error.

Answer (score 0):

Find code in template / CMS page/block or where ever it comes from, and remove the newline after `ev=PageView`.

It does not look like it has something to do with Magento.